# What is the approximate turnaround time for Yolo API access request?

Tags: google-identity

I submitted two requests recently, just wonder how long the request process usually takes. And will I be notified if the requests get rejected?
~ Kudos

Comment: I have the same problem. I got nothing, no request confirmation or any indication of the status... Did you already get something?

Comment: I got nothing either. All I noticed is their request form keeps changing in the last few days and the api console error has been updated. @mesqueeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from them. In the email they mentioned I won't be granted access to One tap API until they have some additional user security in place and it may take a few months.